# Require in gem don't work

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created gem with bundler and puts all my ruby files into '/lib' as documentation suggested.
But I have a problem, after build the gem which "rake build" command and install (gem install pkg/gem) I can't use it because:

> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mygem/client

this is cause because in main file i try to require 'mygem/client.rb' which is in lib/mygem/client.rb
and it is doesn't work :/

This is my gemspec:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'diggy/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "diggy"
  spec.version       = Diggy::VERSION
  spec.authors       = [""]
  spec.email         = [""]

  spec.summary       = %q{: Write a short summary, because Rubygems requires one.}
  spec.description   = %q{: Write a longer description or delete this line.}
  spec.homepage      = ""

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
  # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
  if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
  else
    raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against " \
      "public gem pushes."
  end

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.14"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

Comment: Can you add the results of the commands `gem contents mygem` (`gem contents diggy` in this case), and also `git status` (from within your gems development directory).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main file is named `mygem.rb` and is inside the `lib` folder, you should be able to require the file `lib/mygem/client.rb` with:

```
require 'mygem/client'
```

Notice that I didn't use the `.rb` extension.